# JQuery AJAX call to page method not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an aspx webpage and it is using webservice. The page is coded with javascript. The communication between page and webservice is done by ajax. When the page fires ajax function, the url parameter is assigned to website url (localhost/index.aspx#home). therefore, the aspx cannot reach the webservice. Moreover, I did not do anything with Url parameter anywhere.

What can be the problem here? Any solution?

the ajax code block is here:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",

url: ServiceParameter + "/GET_USER_I_BY_EMAIL",

data: "{username:'" + username + "'}",

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

dataType: "json",

success: function (msg) {

if (msg.d.length == 0 || msg.d == null) {
if (typeof callback == 'function') {
callback(null);
}
}
else if (msg.d <= 0) {
if (typeof callback_err == 'function') {
callback_err(msg.d, 'SendPass');
}
}
else {
var _data = eval("(" + msg.d + ")");
if (typeof callback_err == 'function' && _data[0] != null && typeof _data[0].ErrorCode != 'undefined') {
callback_err(_data, 'SendPass');
}
else if (typeof callback == 'function') {
callback(_data);
}
}
},
error: function (msg) {
if (typeof callback_err == 'function') {
callback_err(-1, 'SendPass');
}
}
});
}
catch (err) {
if (typeof callback_err == 'function') {
callback_err(-2, 'SendPass');
}
}
},
```

Comment: Post service method code and indent your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the next code:

```
$.post(ServiceParameter + "/GET_USER_I_BY_EMAIL", { username: "myUsername" }, 
    function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data)
    }, "json")
    .fail(function() { 
        alert("error"); 
    });
```

Comment: The code and the answers are ok. However, my code block is not working with 'localhost', it is ok with ip address, I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: ServiceParameter + "/GET_USER_I_BY_EMAIL",
data: {username:'" + username + "'},
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (msg) {
 var jsonData = JSON.parse(msg);
 if (jsonData.d.length == 0 || jsonData.d == null) {
 if (typeof callback == 'function') {
 callback(null);
 }
}
```

Comment: The code and the answers are ok. However, my code block is not working with 'localhost', it is ok with ip address, I do not know why.